# How to check for MSIX updates from WPF desktop app?

Tags: c#, desktop-bridge, automatic-updates, msix

We are working on a WPF desktop app packaged using the Desktop Bridge MSIX wrapper, and we need it to detect and automatically apply updates when they are detected, restarting the software.

Research so far suggests it might be possible to use PackageManager from UWP to get hold of the package and check like that, or creating a new "Windows Runtime Component" project with an `IBackgroundTask` that listens to the `windows.updateTask` extension.

I don't know which one is the right one, what's going to be easiest or most reliable. Has anyone had to do this and knows what works?

Thanks

Comment: Check this blog post, it has enough information to get you started: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Dev-AppConsult/Handling-application-updates-with-App-Installer-and-MSIX-in/ba-p/355389

Comment: @Styxxy Thanks, I was already aware of `Package.Current.CheckUpdateAvailabilityAsync()` but the end of that article gives me more confidence that's the right path to go down.

Comment: hi @Nintynuts, above case link could solve your issue?

Comment: @nico-zhu-msft We ended up going a different simpler route to circumvent the issue that required doing this, so I'm not sure. We do have a different issue where the app is installed for two users, and when one account detects the update and installs it, the other accounts' app needs repairing via the app settings for it to work (shows 0 bytes for all sizes before repair).